# Simple Java Animation using JFrame and JPanel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, animation

Ok, so the program's purpose is to just draw and oval and move it across the screen. The code compiles on Eclipse without an error, but when run, no oval is drawn or moved across the screen. I have been researching, and it seems that threads have to do a lot with this, but do I need one for this simple program? I am obviously new to GUI programming with Swing so I would appreciate an explanation or link to one for any additions to the program regarding threads or such related concepts.

```
public class Game extends JPanel
{
    int x =0;
    int y =0;

    private void moveBall()
    {

        x+=1;
        y+=1;
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animation");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        while (true)
        {
            game.moveBall();
            game.repaint();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it probably was, the problem mostly likely is, it simply moved so fast that it was never updated to the screen...

Comment: Probably the problem: you try to move the ball in a while loop. Either this will move way too fast, or it won't even appear in the frame because the frame itself isn't being repainted. It's probably not that the frame isn't being repainted because you don't even see an oval. Use a Timer

Comment: Ok, so how would i reduce the speed? Is is possible/easier to do this with threads? Is that what thread.sleep(millisecond param) does? @MadProgrammer

Comment: How would this be done? @Quincunx

Comment: a quick and ugly way would be to use a `float` instead if `int` for coords and add a very small amount to it each iteration.

Comment: @imgolden62 You might be able to do that. However, the right way is to use a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

Comment: Ok thank you for the link, so the timer does somewhat make sense. However, what part of my program would go into the actionPerformed method? would I just the statements in moveBall into this method? What if I have multiple different methods? Do they all go in that one method or? Thanks in advance, @Quincunx

Comment: For a `JPanel` the `public void paint (Graphics g) { super.paint(g);` code should be `public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g);`..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The likely problem is, that thread is running too fast for the UI, the UI is been shown well after the "ball" has left the visible area.

You need to do a couple of things...

First, you need to make sure that the updates are scheduled properly within the Event Dispatching Thread and secondly, that there is a short delay between updates.  For example, 25fps is about a 40 millisecond delay between updates, 60fps is about 16 milliseconds

There are a number of ways to achieve this, depending what it is you hope to achieve, for example, you could simply use `Thread.sleep` to cause the thread to pause for a small amount of time between updates.  The problem with this is Swing is not thread safe and all updates to the UI should be made within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.

While you program is only simply, it's possible that a paint cycle could run while you updating it's state, resulting in a dirty update.

Another solution might be to use a Swing `Timer` which will allow you schedule updates at a regular interval which are triggered within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, making it safer to use.

Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details.

As an example...

[image: Moving Ball]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class BallAnimation {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BallAnimation();
    }

    public BallAnimation() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;

        public TestPane() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(40, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    moveBall();
                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void moveBall() {
            x++;
            y++;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            g2d.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

    }

}
```

As a side note, unless you really have reason to do so, you should avoid overriding `paint` and instead use `paintComponent`

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot. Thank you for recommending threads as unsafe. All I added was the Game constructed with the statements for the timer inside and it works. However, I am slightly lost with what is in the lines of the BallAnimation constructor (except for the frame statements). Could you summarize what this is exactly and why it is necessary? Thanks in advance. @MadProgammer

Comment: Basically, `EventQueue.invokeLater` is ensuring that UI is created and shown from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread (making it thread safe), see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details. `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` is just setting the look and feel used by Swing to the current System's look and feel, I don't like the metal look at feel

Comment: So if I use EventQueue.invokeLater to make the program thread safe, would I then be able to safely use Adem's thread method? @MadProgrammer

Comment: No.  The "main" thread (which calls the `main` method) and the Event Dispatching Thread are two different threads.  Updating the UI from the "main" thread (or any other thread) would violate the single threading rules of Swing.  The "simple" solution is to use a Swing `Timer` as it synchronises the updates required by the UI within the context of the EDT (you can't update the state AND paint at the same time).  You could do this manually, but it increases the complexity of the solution.

Comment: If you were to use a `BufferStrategy`, you could gain control of the paint process, then it wouldn't matter so much, but you increase the complexity of the solution...

Comment: Well thank you for all the help! You have definitely increased my knowledge on Java GUI programming. I know I'm not supposed to post thanks, but oh well. @MadProgrammer

Answer (score -2):

try your loop with sleep as simplest way to fit your code. main is actually a thread. and `JFrame` creates its own thread.

```
while (true)
{
   game.moveBall();
   game.repaint();
   try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (Exception e){}
}
```

and I just realized, you dont paint your whole screen with a default color.

change your paint method to this

```
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.white); //default color
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()); // fill whole canvas
    g.setColor(Color.black); //change color
    g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30); // draw oval
}
```

Comment: FYI: Swing itself is not thread safe, while only a simple example, a more complex update process could cause dirty updates as paint cycles can occur independently of the programmers requests

Comment: yes, but he is just wanting to draw a simple oval shape. as my explanation, this is the simplest way

Comment: *"and I just realized, you dont paint your whole screen with different color."* - `paint`, via a call to `paintComponent` (via calling `super.paint`) will do this. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Simple and misleading

Comment: I did many 2d games. I just provide my "misleading" know how as a game developer point of view

Comment: If that's your approach, then you've been doing it wrong. If you were to teach someone to shoot, you wouldn't just show them how to pull the trigger. You'd teach them about gun safety first. Same thing here. We need to teach people how to work within the requirements of the API/framework, which will help prevent them from "shooting themselves in the foot" as they increase the complexity of the problem. Build from a strong foundation and your house won't fall down around ;)

Comment: Agree with @MadProgrammer, this approach is not the way to go.  -1

Comment: I dont see any wrong approach to use "main" as a thread. new thread can be used, but also "main" can be used as a thread. also, question itself has also already an approach. I just try to show what is missing in his approach. and one of original quesiton "do I need one (thread) of those". and I said, no, it can work without new thread. you said yes. but, I can show that it works without new thread

Comment: Thank you for your input. It seems like a very simple fix. However, I am also trying to understand MadProgrammers thread safety statement. If this created problems in more complex programs, then why not use a timer? For 2D platform games, did you continue to use threads throughout your different games? Or did you eventually switch to a timer? @Adem

Comment: @Adem The thing that is "wrong" is you are updating state variables which are required by the paint process in an unsafe manner.  A paint cycle could be triggered at any time, without your intervention or knowledge, so it's possible for the UI to be using "stale" information as part of it's update process.  You need to isolate these changes some how to prevent this possibility. The update and paint process should be atomic