# Drop down icon missing on awt choice widget

Tags: java, awt

Running my java awt code on Linux MintOsv20. The program extends `java.awt.Frame` and adds to it a simple choice menu of fruits, which upon selection will update a textfield. But alas, the drop down menu is not having its caret icon.

```
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.setLayout( new GridLayout( 1, 1 ));
        Choice c = new Choice();
        c.add( "mangoes" );
        c.add( "apples" );
        c.add( "oranges" );
        p.add( c );
        this.add( p, BorderLayout.NORTH );
```

produces the output as,

[image: Missing Caret]

Another one of my Mint os machine also had this issue.
Can some learned counsel guide me on this?

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using AWT instead of Swing?

Comment: i am a web developer trying to get my hands wet with java gui. since awt predates swing, i like to explore awt in-depth before trying swing.

Comment: You might want to read about the [differences between AWT and Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/408830/5645656). AWT is not reliably platform-independent, and so it may not behave as desired on certain operating systems (whereas Swing will). The issue with your drop-down menu could be one of these circumstances.

Comment: Maybe, component-wise swing is rich compared to awt. But, awt has its own canvas class where can i do my own drawings, transforms, scales, and even animations. Those things, i haven't seen anyone doing it using swing.

Comment: You may have not seen it yet, but it's everywhere. Swing *does* support these functions. You can read a little about it [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#swing), and a quick google search can yield many examples such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27475048/simple-java-animation-using-jframe-and-jpanel).